# Trying to make linear regression model for machine learning, keep getting error

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I recently posted here saying that I kept getting an error with my input, in which people told me to use numpy's reshape command. However I keep getting this error now from this code:

```
X_train= X_train.reshape(-1, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = y.reshape(-1, 1)
myModel = LinearRegression() 

myModel.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Error:
'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'
this comes up when running the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using:
`X_train.reshape(-1,1)`

Try using:
`X_train.values.reshape(-1,1)`

Overall code:

```
X_train = X_train.values.reshape(-1, 1)
X_test = X_test.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = y_train.values.reshape(-1, 1)
myModel = LinearRegression() 

myModel.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 1)

myModel = LinearRegression() 

myModel.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Hi, this still comes up with the same error

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
X_train= X_train.values.reshape(-1, 1)
X_test = X_test.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = y.values.reshape(-1, 1)
myModel = LinearRegression() 

myModel.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

It will work